# GeoPoint off Parse based on Date

Tags: ios, parsing, date

I have an array of GeoPoints pulled off of parse and displayed on a map view. I want the annotations to be displayed on the day they occur. I have a column titled Date in Parse but cannot figure out the proper format or something because I cannot figure it out.

Here is my current code. Any suggestions?

```
PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
[query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:point withinMiles:50.0];
[query includeKey:kPAWParseUserKey];
[query whereKey:@"date" equalTo:today];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    .....
}];
```

Comment: First your code is very hard to read, because nobody knows what object  'query' is. Second you are sending a NSDate object to query. Please check if this is correct or if the object should be converted to a NSString (representing a specific date format) or a double (representing seconds/milliseconds).